# Strange behavior with css

Tags: html, css

For some reason my footer border is at the top of the page while the text is at the bottom.  Can anyone tell me why it's doing this?

Your can see the page [here](http://accentudate.com/new/footer-error.htm):

I would expect the red line to be just above my footer. What am I missing?

Comment: As mentioned in the answers below, you just need to handle your floats correctly. [Adding `clear: both` to your footer element will fix the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/9wnSN/) but I suggest reading the link in @H Bellamy's answer to understand how to work with floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats can cause layout issues like this. Since you are only using them on your content containers you can remove the `float: left;` from `.search_summary_container` and add `display: inline-block;`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/HSNNZ/

```
.search_summary_container {
    height: auto;
    width: 480px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #c1d1da;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add clear:both to your footer:

```
<div style="padding-top:10px;border-top: solid 1px #ff0000; font-size:11px; clear:both;">...</div>
```

Explanation: If you have a float left and a float right, then, the content that comes after will go under your floats. So by clearing, it resets the floats and renders it after the content that is floated.

Answer (score 0):

In the footer, just set the css to `clear:both`.

Read this article: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/